# How do I surely get spam for my research project?

Tags: email, spam

I have an unusual problem for a project I'm working on - I need to receive spam. Does anyone know how to get on a spammers email list?

For the curious - I'm interested to know if applying reverse dns and SPF on an email server actually blocks spam and/or ham so I've written a smtp server that will check them. I just need to be spammed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search for "Enter email to win" in your favorite search engine and enter your email.
And who knows, besides getting spam, you might also win something :)

**edit:**
Also make sure, that mail server which you are using is not doing any spam filtering already.
The "public" address for our company gets tonnes of spam each day without filtering.

Come to think of it, you could also set up a dummy web page with the email address for spam on it and get it indexed by search engines. This is how we get spam. Although we are not specifically looking for it.

Comment: This way we get all the usual suspects. Nigerian Diamond/Money Scam. Russian Oil Scam, Wife-to-be from remote part of the world with dead husband scam, Corrupt Banker money scam, Buy whatever cheap advertisments, etc.... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
One way is to put your email address on as many forums as you can. Like this:

stevej@exegro.info
kjones@exegro.info
clane@exegro.info
nadav.kozlovsky@exegro.info
SKL@exegro.info
glenn@exegro.info
robn@exegro.info

Spammer are sure to pick this up.
```